# Python List Comprehensions: Create list b from list a, excluding repeats

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to solve this problem using list comprehensions. I want to take the list:

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89]
```

and create a new list `b` containing all the numbers from `a` that are below 5, **excluding repeats**.

I can do this using a for loop:

```
b = list()
for i in a:
    if i < 5 and i not in b:
        b.append(i)
```

which gives me `[1, 2, 3]`, but when I try this using a list comprehension:

```
b = list()
b = [i for i in a if i not in b and i < 5]
```

I get a list with repeated values: `[1, 1, 2, 3]`

*Is there a way to exclude repeated values when using list comprehensions?*

Comment: Add b =  set(b) after your code. set() lets you pick only the unique elements from the given array.

Comment: If you really want to do it in a list comprehension without the `set` trick above, you'll need to test for repetitions in the original list, something like: ```[n for i, n in enumerate(a) if (n < 5) and (n not in a[:i-1])]``` (not tested, careful with `i == 0`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `set`, you get your list without repeats.

```
>>> set(a)
{1, 2, 3, 34, 5, 8, 13, 21, 55, 89}
```

So you can just use (*almost*) the same list comprehension you were using with `set(a)` instead of `a`:

```
b = [i for i in set(a) if i<5]
#[1, 2, 3]
```

Note that there is no need to instantiate your list `b` using `b  = list()` first

Comment: Note that sets destroy the order of the list.

Comment: True, depends on what OP wants to do, but if order matters, another strategy needs to be taken

Comment: @sacul I hadn't learned about `set()` yet, thanks for that! Also, the only reason I used `b = list()` in my code was because without it my list comprehension attempt gave me a `NameError` about `b` not being defined. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

That happens because "b" is still empty while python is creating a temporary list. "b" gets assigned only after list comprehension has created the list.